# RubyMineでのモデルのアトリビュートの補完

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubymine

RubyMineでモデルのattributeの補完はできないのでしょうか？
（DB的な言い方をすると、テーブルのカラム名の補完になります）

```
モデルクラス名.アトリビュート名
```

上記のように、モデルクラス名の後のドット以下で補完されることを想定しています。

もし、できないのであれば、
`ActiveRecord::Base.descendants`
でカラム名が取得できるので、ショートカットキーの設定ファイルを作って、RubyMineにショートカットキー経由で補完させようと思うのですが、ショートカットキーで乗り切る方針の方も可能でしょうか？（どのディレクトリにどんなファイルを作ればよいのか？）

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`モデルクラス名.アトリビュート名`

とは `Post.title` のような補完ということでしょうか？
このような入力をすることはないと思うのですが、どういう状況で使われますか？

`モデルのインスタンス.アトリビュート`であれば

```
post = Post.first
post.title
```

のような形であれば `.` を入力した時点から補完候補が表示されるはずです。

Comment: なるほど。おっしゃる通り、普通にソースを構築するとありえない状況ですね（だからRubyMineに実装されてないのか）。　補完させて、どんなカラムがあったかなといったようなイレギュラーな確認方法や、シンボルとしてカラム名を渡したいときに補完させてから、`モデル名.`の部分を`:`に変える感じでプログラミングしようという発想でした。